# PHP drop keys to build another array

Tags: php, arrays

I am working inside an existing program that has a function that brings back more results than I need. I am trying not to rebuild the function. I just need to cut down the array to a usable size. The array looks like this:

```
array (size=2)
0 => 
array (size=24)
  'event' => '2013-07-22' 
  'endDate' => '0000-00-00' 
  'startTime' => '09:00:00' 
  'endTime' => '09:20:00' 
  'duration' => '1200'
  'recurrtype' => '0' 
  'recurrspec' => 
  'recurrfreq' => '0' 
  'catid' => '9' 
  'eid' => '13714'
  'title' => 'Physical' 
  'hometext' => 'CALLING PT # NOT IN SERV.' 
  'fname' => 'John' 
  'mname' => '' 
  'lname' => 'Bass Jr' 
  'id' => '993' 
  'pubpid' => '993' 
  'phone_home' => '555-111-2222'
  'phone_cell' => ''
  'ufname' => 'Dr' 
  'umname' => 'B'
  'ulname' => 'No'
  'uprovider_id' => '2' 
  'catname' => 'Physical'
1 => 
array (size=24)
  'event' => '2013-07-22' 
  'endDate' => '0000-00-00' 
  'startTime' => '09:00:00' 
  'endTime' => '09:20:00' 
  'duration' => '1200'
  'recurrtype' => '0' 
  'recurrspec' => 
  'recurrfreq' => '0' 
  'catid' => '9' 
  'eid' => '13717'
  'title' => 'Physical' 
  'hometext' => '' 
  'fname' => 'James' 
  'mname' => '' 
  'lname' => 'Lenny Jr' 
  'id' => '993' 
  'pubpid' => '993' 
  'phone_home' => '555-111-2222'
  'phone_cell' => ''
  'ufname' => 'Dr' 
  'umname' => 'B'
  'ulname' => 'No'
  'uprovider_id' => '2' 
  'catname' => 'Physical'
```

The desired array that I need is this:

```
 array (size=2)
 0 =>
  'event' => '2013-07-22' 
  'startTime' => '09:00:00' 
  'fname' => 'John' 
  'lname' => 'Bass Jr' 
  'phone_home' => '555-111-2222'
 1 =>
  'event' => '2013-07-22' 
  'startTime' => '09:00:00' 
  'fname' => 'James' 
  'lname' => 'Lenny Jr' 
  'phone_home' => '555-111-2222'
```

I have searched the PHP manual for a function that would return me this array but just couldn't see my way past how to filter out the keys that I don't need. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: a loop and then unset, to remove those you don't want or a new array based on the ones you want, but is it going to be worth it?

Comment: Or `array_intersect_key`, possibly with `array_map` and using it in a callback/closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your own function like:

```
function get_desired_array($theArray)
{
   $desired_keys = array( 'event','startTime', 'fname', 'lname','phone_home');
   $desired_array = array();

   foreach ($theArray as $childArray)
   {
      foreach ($childArray as $k => $v)
      {
          if(in_array($k, $desired_keys))
          {
             $desired_array[$k] = $v;
          }
      }
   }

   return $desired_array;
 }
```

And run the function:

```
$desired_array = get_desired_array($theArray);

//you can now:
var_dump($desired_array);
```

Comment: Charlie thanks this gets me closer but there is no output or only a single output if I comment out the return. Your instructions said to create a function but you did not write this like a function. Sorry if I am missing your point.

Comment: Sorry too, I just thought you need to be more `creative`, I've completed my function.

Answer (score 0):

After taking the lead that was given me. I tried something really simple. I knew I needed a foreach loop. So I constructed the loop this way:

```
$parentArray = getFunction();
  foreach ($parentArray as $childArray) {

       $desired_array[] = array (
            "Fname" => $childArray['fname'],
            "Lname" => $childArray['lname'],
            "Phone" => $childArray['phone_home'],
            "Date" => $childArray['event'],
            "Time" => $childArray['startTime']                                
          );

    }
```

It appears that the foreach loop only returned the values that I specified in the $childArray and ignored all the rest.

Answer (score 0):

you can use function : array_column .  But need your php >= 5.5.0

Answer (score 0):

There is special function for that in PHP: [array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

This is the code:

```
$originArray = array(
  // your original array here
  // 0 => array(...)
  // 1 => array(...)
  // ...
  // n => array(...)
);
$desiredKeys = array_flip(array('event', 'startTime', 'fname', 'lname', 'phone_home'));
foreach ($originArray as $index => $subArray)
{
    $originArray[$index] = array_intersect_key($subArray, $desiredKeys);
}
```

PS. I used array_flip to convert values to keys, as array_intersect_key does comparing by keys. Another way to define $desiredKeys:

```
$desiredKeys = array('event'=>1, 'startTime'=>1, 'fname'=>1, 'lname'=>1, 'phone_home'=>1);
```